# Changing an integer grade into a character grade using a switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

Using the switch statement, write a program that converts a numerical grade into a letter
grade:

> Enter numerical grade: 84
> Letter grade: B

Use the following grading scale:

> A = 90-100, B = 80-89, C = 70-79, D = 60-69, F = 0-59.

Print an error message if the grade is larger than `100` or less than `0`.

Hint: Break the grade into two digits, then use a switch statement to test the ten's digit.

How can I change the code to let `100` become `A`? I input `100` and the output was `F`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int front_number, back_number;

    printf("Enter numerical grade: ");
    scanf("%1d%1d", &front_number, &back_number);

    printf("Letter grade: ");

    switch (front_number){
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
        printf("F");
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("D");
        break;
    case 7:
        printf("C");
        break;
    case 8:
        printf("B");
        break;
    case 9:
        printf("A");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kaylum The assignment (I assume this is homework) says that `switch` should be used.

Comment: I knew how to do in (if else statement) , but the question want me using switch

Comment: And if you really have to use a `switch` statement (as you claim), you could perhaps consider rounding (down) to the nearest 10 and `switch`ing on the result.

Comment: Is `00` a valid input? If not, then if the first digit is 0 you could interpret that as 100.

Comment: The assignment is faulty to say to break the number into two digits when a valid input is “100”, which is three digits. Just scan the input with `%d` into a single number, say `grade`, and then use `switch (grade/10)` and include a `case 10:`. Distinguishing 100 from 101 for reporting the error will require either an `if` statement or some shenanigans (perhaps just a second `switch`). I recommend finding a new teacher.

Comment: Followup to Eric Postpischil's comment: it would even be better to write a function `char NumericGradeToLetterGrade(int numericgrade)`.

Comment: Why is there no grade E? Is that a grade system used by some specific country?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned `default`.

Comment: @Lundin yap no E

Comment: @Lundin in some countries it is A-D if you passed the test and F if you failed.

Comment: The cases where you should print an error message are completely missing. That is the time where `default` might come into the game. But beware of `100` being the only allowed value with a leading `10`.

Answer (score 0):

In a real world program you would likely create a struct per grade, then search through a table of read-only elements. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int  low_limit;
  int  high_limit;
  char grade;
} grade_t;

int main (void)
{
  const grade_t grade[] =
  {
    {  0,  59, 'F' },
    { 60,  69, 'D' },
    { 70,  79, 'C' },
    { 80,  89, 'B' },
    { 90, 100, 'A' },
  };
  
  int input = 82;
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof grade/sizeof *grade; i++)
  {
    if(input <= grade[i].high_limit)
    {
      printf("%d gives %c", input, grade[i].grade);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a naive linear search method but since the amount of items is so limited, it's likely quite efficient. Alternatively you could use standard C `bsearch`, in case you have a larger amount of sorted data.

Notably, we don't even need to know the lower limit since that's implicit by the previous item in the array.

Comment: This does not conform to the problem specification, which says “Using the switch statement” and “Print an error message if the grade is larger than 100 or less than 0.”

Answer (score 0):

It is better to *not* read two digits, because:

- This tries to read the input and process this input in one step, while these are separate processes.
- If the input is `100`, it will leave the last `0` character in the input stream.
- The cases `10` and `100` are indistinguishable.

The hint to "break the grade into two digits" is misleading for similar reasons.

**The (probably) intended solution**

Here is, what I assume to be, more or less the intended solution. It reads the entire (unsigned) integer, and uses a switch for its value divided by 10. The one not-so-elegant part is the default case (more of an "else" here) which has to distinguish between valid 3-digit input (i.e. `100` and invalid input.
Technically, part of the input is now being handled by an if-statement instead of a switch, but this is the most sensible solution given the problem statement. A bit better would be to catch the edge case `grade == 100` at the top of function and leave the default case to only return an error value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char gradeUintToChar(unsigned int grade);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter numerical grade: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    unsigned int gradeUint;
    if (scanf("%u", &gradeUint) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char gradeChar = gradeUintToChar(gradeUint);
    if (gradeChar == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "gradeUintToChar: Invalid parameter\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Letter grade: %c\n", gradeChar);
}

char gradeUintToChar(unsigned int grade)
{
    switch (grade / 10U)
    {
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
        return 'F';

    case 6:
        return 'D';

    case 7:
        return 'C';

    case 8:
        return 'B';

    case 9:
        return 'A';

    default:
        if (grade == 100U)
            return 'A';
        else
            return (char) 0; // Indicates failure
    }
}
```

**The GNU case ranges solution**

There is a GNU extension called [case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges) which allows for this to be implemented rather directly using a switch. Since this is non-standard C, this is generally *not* a recommended method.

Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char gradeUintToChar(unsigned int grade);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter numerical grade: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    unsigned int gradeUint;
    if (scanf("%u", &gradeUint) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char gradeChar = gradeUintToChar(gradeUint);
    if (gradeChar == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "gradeUintToChar: Invalid parameter\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Letter grade: %c\n", gradeChar);
}

char gradeUintToChar(unsigned int grade)
{
    switch (grade)
    {
    case 0 ... 59:
        return 'F';

    case 60 ... 69:
        return 'D';

    case 70 ... 79:
        return 'C';

    case 80 ... 89:
        return 'B';

    case 90 ... 100:
        return 'A';

    default:
        return (char) 0; // Indicates failure
    }
}
```